# EJS not rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I simply make a little templating system with EJS, Express.js on node.js but the render is a bit wtf...

[image: here the render]

And here the code of my server.js :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
//var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
//var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');

//var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Here the config of page
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //Accueil -> redirection vers un chat aléatoire
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(500).send('Test !');
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(500).send('Test !');
});

app.get('/auth/login', function(req,res){
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(500).send('Test !');
});


app.get('/auth/register', function(req,res){
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(500).send('Test !');
});

app.get('/chat', function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.render('redirect.ejs', {});
})

app.get('/chat/:chatnum', function(req,res){
    if(parseInt(req.params.chatnum, 10) < 101){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(500).send('Test !' + req.params.chatnum);
    }
    else {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.status(404).send('Page introuvable !!');
    }        
});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.status(404).send('Page introuvable !');
});

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
//var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(8080);
//httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

(i've disabled https currently)

So if someone know why it is not rendering html as html but as text...

Thanks in advance...

EDIT : P.S. you can see the template code in the browser as it is in the file redirecting.ejs
EDIT 2 : adding code format for redirect.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <title>Redirecting...</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <h1 style="text-align: center">Redirecting...</h1>

    <script>window.location.href = "/ + " (Math.random().trunc() * 100) + 1</script>    

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not working... Tried with text/html and simply remove the line but same issue not working.

Comment: have you tried a different view engine?
app.set('view engine', 'html');

Comment: Please add the actual, textual, template and not an image of it.

Comment: Sure... Adding...

Comment: I would remove the "content-type : text/plain header" and check the header of the response in browser. normally, there should be no content-type header if you do so. If there is, it may be the source of your problem

Comment: Done i've ever tried this look at the first comments...

Comment: Done ok a problem of caching...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the header content-type should not be "text/plain". you can remove the line `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');` for all route who need to send html.

Be aware that response are cached, and if the content do not change but the header does, you will not see the change.

You can use `ctrl+F5` to force reload your page.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');` line from any response that should be returning HTML.

That way the browser will know to render it instead of displaying the raw text.

Comment: Thanks it was it but the page was cached i mean... Thanks all !